# Drag and Drop/Reorder items in wrap panel?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a need to create an interaction in wrap panel to allow drag and drop functionality of items. I generate content in wrap panel dynamically with XMLDataprovider. I was not able to find any similar interaction online. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the work done by [Martin Grayson](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/). It is an open source project on CodePlex titled [Blacklight](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/). There should be both an SL version and WPF version doing what you need to do via the Drag Dock Panel, with source available to get a better understanding on how it is implemented.

To see the sample from above, click WPF then click Drag Dock Panel on the lower left.

**EDIT:** It appears that default WPF support was stripped in 4.3, however jump back to [4.2](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36476) and both the binaries and source have their respective WPF offerings.

Comment: I will try to implement it. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I have hard time implementing it in WPF project. It probably works only in SL at this time. I am still looking something that can be done in WPF project.

Comment: There is a WPF offering. It appears he stripped the default support in 4.3, however go back to 4.2 http://blacklight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36476 and both the source and the binaries have a separate WPF offering

Comment: It is great WPF control. I really like it. I was able to have WPF version with Backlight 4.2 version. However, I have few problems with it but the most important is to have this drop and drop functionality happening in WrapPanel. Now, it is working in a Grid but I need to be able to change to WrapPanel. I am wondering if you know how to do it in Blacklight. Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77 Not certain I have the details to help you...in standard WPF controls swapping out the underlying template is all that is needed; you may be able to post on the Blacklight codeplex site to see if someone can help you there...